# How to 'mask' a string or array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been asked to create a simple 'Hangman' for a Tafe assignment, but I've run into two issues.

One is that the instructions ask me to 'mask' the word in an array so that it's easier to update as the player guesses letters, but I'm unsure how to do this.
I currently have it so that the word is split and each of its letters saved into an array called letterArray as well as the full word save into toBeGuessed. I've reached the point where I have to update the ****** to look more like the word each time a letter is guessed.

I found the following advice when looking over similar questions:

> Keep 2 copies of the string, the word and the obfuscated one (the one
>   containing '-') (preferably as char array or string builder). When a
>   user guesses a letter, search the non-obfuscated version for all
>   instances of that letter. each time you find a match, change the '-'
>   at that index in the obfuscated string to the correct letter.

But I'm unsure how to do this. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

The other issue I'm having is that every time I press 'play' all of the 'letters' become unclickable, but I can click on them before 'play' is clicked?
I tried removing the 'play' button all together but then the letters won't respond at all.

[My current code](http://www.codecademy.com/javaWhiz66294/codebits/ZUAsL6/edit) (it won't work on JSFiddle for some reason)

### JS

```
var listOfWords = ["aardvarks", "determine", "different", "greatness", "miserable", "trappings", "valuables", "xylophone"];
var toBeGuessed = listOfWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfWords.length)];
var lettersArray = toBeGuessed.split('');
var guesses = 0;
var playerguess = 'dunno';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').hide();
    $('#guessIt').hide();
    $('#play').click(function() {
        $('#theWord').html(toBeGuessed);
        for (var i = 1; i < toBeGuessed.length + 1; i++) {
            $('#masked').append('* ');
        }
        $('#play').hide();
    });
    $('.letter').click(function() {
        value = this.value;
        guesses += 1;
        found = $.inArray(value, lettersArray) > -1;
        if (found === true) {
            this.style.color = 'green';
        } else {
            this.style.color = 'red';
        }
        if (guesses === 5) {
            alert('Your five guesses are up! What do you think the word is?');
            $('#input').show();
            $('#guessIt').show();
        }
    });
    $('#guessIt').click(function() {        
            playerguess = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase();
            if (playerguess === toBeGuessed) {
                alert('Congrats! You win!');
            } else {
                alert('I\'m sorry, but that\'s not correct. It was ' + toBeGuessed + '! You lose.');
                $('#hangman').html('<p>___________<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(_)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; /|\\ <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/ \\<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;_|___</p>');
            }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A string mask is a sequence of values that overlays the string to indicate whether or not to show characters at certain positions. For the string "BAD", to show say "-A-" the mask is "010". If treated as a binary number, it can be represented efficiently in some other base, say "2" in base 10. So step 1 is to generate the mask, step 2 is to apply it to the saved string. Incidentally, you don't have to convert the "original" string to an array, you can use [*charAt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.4) to get the character at a particular index.

Comment: so in your 'BAD' example, 0 means to hide it and 1 means to show the character?

Comment: @RobG: I would suggest to use an array of booleans with the same length as the string instead (both for simplicity, and for words that are longer than 31 characters)

Comment: Sure, I should have said "…the mask **might** be…", mask values can be any sensible Type. In ancient times, bit masks were popular, e.g. in UNIX permissions 7 -> 111 -> rwx or read, write, execute permission and 0 -> 000 -> --- or no permission. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listOfWords = ["aardvarks", "determine", "different", "greatness", "miserable", "trappings", "valuables", "xylophone"];
var toBeGuessed = listOfWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfWords.length)];
var lettersArray = toBeGuessed.split('');
var guesses = 0;
var playerguess = 'dunno';

    $('#input').hide();
    $('#guessIt').hide();
    $('#play').click(function() {
        // "mask" `toBeGuessed`
        var val = toBeGuessed.replace(/[a-z]/gi, "*")
        $('#theWord').html(val);        
        //for (var i = 1; i < toBeGuessed.length + 1; i++) {
        //    $('#masked').append('* ');
        // }
        $('#play').hide();
    });
    $('.letter').click(function() {
        value = this.value;
        guesses += 1;
        found = $.inArray(value, lettersArray) > -1;
        if (found === true) {
            this.style.color = 'green';
            // if `value` in `toBeGuessed` , 
            // "unmask" single `value` (letter) in "masked" `toBeGuessed`
            if (toBeGuessed.indexOf(value) != -1) {
                $('#theWord').text(function(i, letter) {                    
                    var _letter = letter.split("")
                    // if selected letter previously selected , 
                    // apply `firstLetter`
                    , test = new RegExp(value, "i").test(letter)
                    // "unmask" first letter in `toBeGuessed` ,
                    // when letter selected 
                    , firstLetter = toBeGuessed.indexOf(value)
                    // "unmask" 1n+2 letters ,
                    // in `toBeGuessed` 
                    // when _same_ letter selected more than once
                    , nextLetters = $.inArray(value,toBeGuessed,letter.lastIndexOf(value) +1);
                    _letter.splice(test ? nextLetters : firstLetter, 1, toBeGuessed.charAt(test ? nextLetters : firstLetter));
                    // return "mask" , with selected letters "unmasked"
                    return _letter.join("")
                });   
            }
        } else {
            this.style.color = 'red';
        }
        if (guesses === 5) {
            alert('Your five guesses are up! What do you think the word is?');
            $('#input').show();
            $('#guessIt').show();
        }
    });
    $('#guessIt').click(function() {        
            playerguess = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase();
            if (playerguess === toBeGuessed) {
                alert('Congrats! You win!');
            } else {
                alert('I\'m sorry, but that\'s not correct. It was ' + toBeGuessed + '! You lose.');
                $('#hangman').html('<p>___________<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(_)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; /|\\ <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/ \\<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;_|___</p>');
            }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/g5z5b4qy/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var listOfWords = ["aardvarks", "determine", "different", "greatness", "miserable", "trappings", "valuables", "xylophone"];
var toBeGuessed = listOfWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfWords.length)];
var lettersArray = toBeGuessed.split('');
var guesses = 0;
var playerguess = 'dunno';
    
    $('#input').hide();
    $('#guessIt').hide();
    $('#play').click(function() {
        // "mask" `toBeGuessed`
        var val = toBeGuessed.replace(/[a-z]/gi, "*")
        $('#theWord').html(val);        
        //for (var i = 1; i < toBeGuessed.length + 1; i++) {
        //    $('#masked').append('* ');
        // }
        $('#play').hide();
    });
    $('.letter').click(function() {
        value = this.value;
        guesses += 1;
        found = $.inArray(value, lettersArray) > -1;
        if (found === true) {
            this.style.color = 'green';
            if (toBeGuessed.indexOf(value) != -1) {
                $('#theWord').text(function(i, letter) {                    
                    var _letter = letter.split("")
                    // if selected letter previously selected , 
                    // apply `first`
                    , test = new RegExp(value, "i").test(letter)
                    // "unmask" first letter in `toBeGuessed` ,
                    // when letter selected 
                    , firstLetter = toBeGuessed.indexOf(value)
                    // "unmask" 1n+2 letters ,
                    // in `toBeGuessed` 
                    // when _same_ letter selected more than once
                    , nextLetters = $.inArray(value,toBeGuessed,letter.lastIndexOf(value) +1);
                    _letter.splice(test ? nextLetters : firstLetter, 1,  toBeGuessed.charAt(test ? nextLetters : firstLetter));
                    // return "mask" , with selected letters "unmasked"
                    return _letter.join("")
                });   
            }
        } else {
            this.style.color = 'red';
        }
        if (guesses === 5) {
            alert('Your five guesses are up! What do you think the word is?');
            $('#input').show();
            $('#guessIt').show();
        }
    });
    $('#guessIt').click(function() {        
            playerguess = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase();
            if (playerguess === toBeGuessed) {
                alert('Congrats! You win!');
            } else {
                alert('I\'m sorry, but that\'s not correct. It was ' + toBeGuessed + '! You lose.');
                $('#hangman').html('<p>___________<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(_)<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; /|\\ <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/ \\<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;_|___</p>');
            }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #081208;
    color: white;
}

#hangman {
    background: url('#');
    width: 29%;
    height: 80%;
    font-size: 40px;
    float: left;
}
#masked { 
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-family: Walter Turncoat;
    font-size: 64px;
}
#play {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Walter Turncoat;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#play:hover {
    color: gray;
}
#guessIt {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Walter Turncoat;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#guessIt:hover {
    color: gray;
}
#letters {
    float: right;  
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.letter {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Walter Turncoat;
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
    outline:none
}
.letter:hover {
    color: gray;
}
input {
width:230px;
font-family:Walter Turncoat;
background: none;
border: none;
color: white;
height: 35px;
font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hangman"><p>___________
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| <!-- head -->
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| <!-- arms -->
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| <!-- body -->
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| <!-- feet -->
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;_|___</p></div>
<div id="letters">
<button class="letter" id="a" value="a">A</button> 
<button class="letter" id="b" value="b">B</button>
<button class="letter" id="c" value="c">C</button> 
<button class="letter" id="d" value="d">D</button>
<button class="letter" id="e" value="e">E</button> 
<button class="letter" id="f" value="f">F</button>
<button class="letter" id="g" value="g">G</button> 
<button class="letter" id="h" value="h">H</button>
<br>
<button class="letter" id="i" value="i">I</button> 
<button class="letter" id="j" value="j">J</button>
<button class="letter" id="k" value="k">K</button> 
<button class="letter" id="l" value="l">L</button>
<button class="letter" id="m" value="m">M</button> 
<button class="letter" id="n" value="n">N</button>
<button class="letter" id="o" value="o">O</button> 
<button class="letter" id="p" value="p">P</button>
<br>
<button class="letter" id="q" value="q">Q</button> 
<button class="letter" id="r" value="r">R</button>
<button class="letter" id="s" value="s">S</button> 
<button class="letter" id="t" value="t">T</button>
<button class="letter" id="u" value="u">U</button> 
<button class="letter" id="v" value="v">V</button>
<button class="letter" id="w" value="w">W</button> 
<button class="letter" id="x" value="x">X</button>
<br>
<button class="letter" id="y" value="y">Y</button> 
<button class="letter" id="z" value="z">Z</button>
</div>
<center>
<div id="masked"></div>
<button id="play">Play!</button>
<div id="theWord"></div>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input" placeholder="What's the word?" />

<button id="guessIt">Guess the Word!</button>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Thank you for commenting it so I was able to understand the process :)